# Vue 3 how to pass an optional boolean prop?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm building an app with Vue 3 and TS 4.4 and bundled with Vite 2. I've got a `LoginPage.vue` file with these contents:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps<{
  message?: string;
  redirectOnSubmit?: boolean;
  showRegisterLink?: boolean;
}>();

console.log({ ...props });
</script>

<template>
  ... login form and whatnot
</template>
```

This component is being passed to `vue-router`

```
export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    { name: RouteName.LOGIN, path: "/login", component: LoginPage },
    { name: RouteName.REGISTER, path: "/register", component: RegisterPage },
  ],
});
```

The problem I'm having is when the login page `setup` script gets run, it logs this:

```
{ redirectOnSubmit: false, showRegisterLink: false, message: undefined }
```

Why are my optional boolean props being forced to `false` instead of `undefined`? Is there any way to turn this off? If I switch `message` to `message?: boolean`, it also gets switched to `false`.

I'd like to default these props to `true` if nothing is passed, but as-is there's no way for me to distinguish between passing `false` and omitting the props entirely.

Comment: Can you share your component that receives props ?

Comment: @Batuhan That's the `LoginPage.vue` component. It's passed directly to `vue-router`, so it's not being passed any props. That's the problem. Vue is acting like the `LoginPage` component is receiving `redirect-on-submit="false"` but really I'm not passing any props to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vue defaults Boolean props to `false` if no `default` was specified in the prop declaration. The author of Vue [explains the reasoning](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4792#issuecomment-275396426):

> The boolean casting follows the same rule of a boolean attribute: presence of any value are casted to true, absence means false.

To default the props to `true`, declare the prop with a `default` option of `true`, using the [*object-based syntax for the prop declaration*](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#props), as seen in this Options API example:

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    myOptionalBool: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true, 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Option 1: `defineProps(props)`

In `<script setup>`, `defineProps()` accepts the prop declaration object (shown above) as a function argument. Since `defineProps()` only accepts *either* the function argument *or* the generic type argument, all props would have to be declared in the function argument:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps({
  message: String,
  showRegisterLink: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  redirectOnSubmit: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
})
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-optional-boolean-prop?file=src%2Fviews%2FLoginPage.vue)

#### Option 2: `withDefaults()` and `defineProps<T>()`

The [`withDefaults()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#default-props-values-when-using-type-declaration) macro can be used with `defineProps<T>()` to specify default values for specific props:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
interface Props {
  message?: string
  redirectOnSubmit?: boolean
  showRegisterLink?: boolean
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  redirectOnSubmit: true,
  showRegisterLink: true,
})
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-optional-boolean-prop-u9xpip?file=src%2Fviews%2FLoginPage.vue)

Comment: How Vue treats boolean props is still a weird part of Vue's API, and is inconsistent with HTML, JS, TS, and Vue itself. See: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4792#issuecomment-1591765678

Comment: thank you so much, why tf is so hard to find this explanation in vue docs ????

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question more explicitly:

You must use `withDefaults` and explicitly pass `undefined` as the default:

```js
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
  message?: string;
  redirectOnSubmit?: boolean;
  showRegisterLink?: boolean;
}>(), {
  redirectOnSubmit: undefined,
  showRegisterLink: undefined
})
```

This forces the optional boolean attributes to be `undefined` instead of `false` when not passed.